# How to make widgets in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, widget, next.js, css-animations, react-animations

I have recently seen the Stripe site and there is a section with a card image that is filling the details automatically and then scrolling to the next tab and again it shows. Refer to this section of the site https://stripe.com/en-in/payments

See this section of above link to stripe site:

[image]

I think these are widgets. I am new to animations. Can anyone suggest how to make these and embed in our webpage with Next.js/React.js?

Answer (score 1):

Upon search I got there are many typing effect packages which we can use . I will list of them
1)https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-typing-animation

2)https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-typical

We can use these packages to create the typing effect .
Note - If you have multiple places where you have to show this animation then can sync them using your javascript methods.

Another simple way of using can be done by simply inserting a GIF for that animation , if you dont want to mess around the code

Feel free to share if there are other ways to do this .

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, I'd do it simulating an auto text (https://youtu.be/t7ePHIsKnnI) and then changing the component using `setTimeOut` or `UseEffect`

Comment: that will remove the problem or auto-typing infinitely but what about clicking automatically and hovering and displaying the list automatically seems like a video but not a video @andresCampuzanoGarzon

Comment: You catch me with it, I suggest to make a gift (not a video) and it won't make it harder to develop.  greetings

Comment: I found some library in react like react-typing-animations but getting problems in implementing that. I am giving a start delay to successive sections but on finish how to reset them . They will again take the time delay and it will go smooth for 2-3 iterations but then next 3-4 animations are rough and then smooth and continues . Any idea to improve it @andres